# Accepted Answer Pinner

Tags: script, answers

### About

As of September 8th, 2021, [accepted answers are no longer pinned on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/4751173) and probably soon on [other sites in the network as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/295232). For some users, this is the realization of a long-standing request; other users might prefer the old situation. For them, I wrote this simple user script which pins the accepted answer at the top.

That is, if it's on the same page (some questions have so many answers they need to be paginated) and self-answers are not pinned (unless they rank highest in votes/oldest/active, as before).

### Installation

- Install the userscript with
  [this direct link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/master/accepted-answer-pinner/accepted-answer-pinner.user.js), or check the source code [here](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/blob/master/accepted-answer-pinner/accepted-answer-pinner.user.js).

<sub>developed & tested with Violentmonkey on Firefox</sub>

Comment: Thanks for contributing this script.  Can you also provide step by step guide on how to install this?  Or provide link to guides on installing similar script.  Many thanks!

Comment: @SeaBean you're welcome. Please have a look at the [script tag wiki](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info).

Comment: @MolbOrg that is going to be the default on almost all sites, see the linked posts.

Comment: I came from that post(almost from a different meta), just decided to join this place and write here not there, lol. idk, at the place, I'm interested in, votes split 50/50 (worldbuilding), not sure we apply for unpinning this way, so at least for desktop, where I can have user scripts, I thought, I may test and keep it if we do not apply for unpinning. I know it already on StackOverflow, but it for a different se